# Do I need to keep a session, when using OAuth and a mobile client application?

Tags: authentication, mobile, oauth, oauth-2.0, authorization

I am new to OAuth and to different authentication mechanisms, and some concepts are a bit weak (I come from the mobile world, and not from the web world). Sorry for the dummy questions.

I want to create a mobile application and a backend that will expose a REST API to the mobile app. 
To authorise the app to access the REST API on behalf of the user, I will use a OAuth flow, so at the end, my app will use an Access Token for accessing BE resources.

From my POV this is enough for all my goals:

- The mobile app calls the endpoint `https://example.com/user`
- The BE receives the request with an Access Token
- BE calls the OAuth introspection endpoint to know to which user the Access Token belongs to.
- The BE endpoint returns user data to the mobile app

For me that seems ok, but I see that some people combine this mechanism with a cookie, to further identify the user using a session.

Do I need a session for my use case? What benefits does it have?

From my POV sessions might be useful only when having a browser based application. Do browser based applications use the access token and session at the same time? Or is the session mapped to an access token on server side?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By default in OAuth there are no cookies or sessions (unless you're using a server side web app).  As a first step I would keep things as above - which looks very standard. It can potentially be useful to model sessions into your API interface though. This will allow your back end to distinguish between a user running 2 instances of your UI - and understand which API requests are coming from which UI instance. An access token doesn't quite give you this - since access tokens get refreshed after a while.